# jquery variable scoop inside if

Tags: javascript

```
if(){
     var1 = "some html"
}

if(){
     console.log(var1);
}
```

the `var1` is undefined, but I thought without using the var make `var1` became a global variable?

like not declare the variable as `var var1`

Comment: The question is not clear, code is incorrect and it is not related to the jquery library.

Comment: Assuming that both conditions evaluate to `true`, the code works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/wLuLH/. `var1` is defined. But even if you used `var var1 = ...;` since JS only has function scope, not block scope.

Answer (score 1):

As [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) mentioned

> JS only has function scope, not block scope

Consider this examples:

ex #1

```
   function Scope1(){
      var1 = "1";  // window.var1 = "1"
    }
    function Scope2(){
      var1 = "2";  // window.var1 = "2"
    }
    function Scope3(){
      var var1 = "3"; // var1 = "3" local variable for the Scope3 function
                      // window.var1 and var1 are different variables
    }
    Scope1();
    console.log(var1); // returns 1
    Scope2();
    console.log(var1); // returns 2
    Scope3();
    console.log(var1); // returns 2
```

ex #2

```
  if(true) {
    var1 = "1"; // window.var1 = "1"
  }
  if(true){
    console.log(var1); // returns 1
    var1 = "2";        // window.var1 = "2"
  }
  console.log(var1);   // returns 2
```

ex #3

```
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  }
  console.log(i); // returns 10, because for is not a function
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know that. This is a very strange behavior for a programming language. :)